# Numpy mixing arrays with multiple index arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3d mesh with points and the locations of the points are
in an array that looks like this:

```
mesh_vectors = np.array([[-0.85758871,  0.8965745 , -0.1427767 ],
                         [-0.23945311,  1.00544977,  1.45797086],
                         [-0.57341832, -1.07448494, -0.11827722],
                         [ 0.05894491, -0.97208506,  1.47583127],
                         [-0.71402085, -0.08872638, -0.12916484],
                         [-0.09181146,  1.01235461,  0.47418442],
                         [-0.09025362,  0.01668115,  1.46690106],
                         [ 0.19773833, -0.95349348,  0.49089319],
                         [ 0.05055711,  0.02909645,  0.48503664]])
```

I have two indexing arrays:

```
idx1 = np.array([4 2 1 6 5 0 1 5])
idx2 = np.array([6 3 0 4 7 2 3 7])
```

these translations correspond to the index arrays:

```
translate_1 = np.array([[ 0.00323021  0.00047712 -0.00422925]
                        [ 0.00153422  0.00022654 -0.00203258]
                        [ 0.00273207  0.00039626  0.00038201]
                        [ 0.0052439   0.00075993  0.00068843]
                        [-0.00414245 -0.00053918  0.00543974]
                        [-0.00681844 -0.00084955  0.00894626]
                        [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
                        [-0.00672519 -0.00099897 -0.00090189]])

translate_2 = np.array([[ 0.00523871  0.00079512  0.00068814]
                        [ 0.00251901  0.00038234  0.00033379]
                        [ 0.00169134  0.00021078 -0.00218737]
                        [ 0.00324106  0.00040338 -0.00422859]
                        [-0.00413547 -0.00058669  0.00544016]
                        [-0.00681223 -0.0008921   0.00894669]
                        [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
                        [-0.00672553 -0.00099677 -0.00090191]])
```

they are currently added to the mesh like this:

```
mesh_vectors[idx1] += translate_1
mesh_vectors[idx2] += translate_2
```

The trouble is, what I really need to add isn't the translations
but the mean of the translations where multiple translations are 
applied to the same mesh point. The indexing arrays can have indices occurring in a variety of different frequencies. Could be [2,2,2,3,4,5] and [1,2,1,1,5,4] though they will always be the same size. I'm trying to do this with numpy for speed but I have the options of using loops on start to generate indexing arrays if needed. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you write it with loops (or pseudo-code) so that we can see more clearly what you are asking for?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
scaled_tr1 = translate_1 / np.bincount(idx1)[idx1,None]
np.add.at(mesh_vectors, idx1, scaled_tr1)
```

Note that the use of `np.add.at` instead of fancy indexing [is required:](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html)

> **ufunc.at(a, indices, b=None)**
>
> Performs unbuffered in place operation on operand `a` for elements specified by `indices`. For addition ufunc, this method is equivalent to `a[indices] += b`, except that results are accumulated for elements that are indexed more than once. For example, `a[[0,0]] += 1` will only increment the first element once because of buffering, whereas `add.at(a, [0,0], 1)` will increment the first element twice.